# Better way to cleanly handle nested XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm working with XML that was designed by somebody who got paid by the level of nesting.  The different xml files always looks something like this:

```
<Car>   
   <Color>
       <Paint>
          <AnotherUselessTag>
               <SomeSemanticBs>
                   <TheImportantData>
```

With LINQ its easy to get what I want:  ( not exactly, but you get the point )

```
from x in car.Descendants("x")
from y in x.Descendants("y")
from z in y.Descendants("z")
select z.WhatIWant();
```

I'm asking if there is a better way to do this?  Some way of navigating the DOM with Linq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are sure that all you want are `TheImporantData` elements from a `Car` element and that `TheImportantData` isn't used as a tag name else where then:-

from x in car.Descendants("TheImportantData")
   select x.WhatIWant();

Will do.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know .Descendants worked like that.  Great answer.

Comment: That examines every one of the element's descendant elements, which can be a problem if your XML is very large.

Comment: @Robert: Interesting point, is there somewhere that can be confirmed.  Typical DOMs would index the element names hence selecting by a single name is quite efficient, but Xml.Linq isn't typical.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the `XNode` extension method `XPathSelectElements`.  In your case:

```
var foo = from x in car.XPathSelectElements("Color/Paint/AnotherUselessTag/SomeSemanticBs/TheImportantData")
select x.WhatIWant();
```

Unlike the `Descendants` method, using XPath in this fashion navigates specifically to the elements you need - e.g. it will only look at `Color` elements under the `Car` element, and only at `Paint` elements under the `Color` elements, and so on.  (You can emulate the less discriminating behavior of the `Descendants` method with the XPath pattern `.//TheImportantData` if you need to.)

Comment: I wish I could have accepted both answers.  This is more what I'm looking for because at least I let the guy behind me know whats going on.